# Does ARCore have session's delegate methods like ARKit has?

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

In ARKit there's a `ARSessionDelegate` protocol what has 4 main methods you can implement to receive captured video frame images and tracking state from an AR session.

Does ARCore API have a similar protocol (interface) with similar methods?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.session.delegate = self       // ARSessionDelegate? protocol
}
```

> 1. This method provides a newly captured ARCamera image and accompanying AR information to the delegate:

```
func session(ARSession, didUpdate: ARFrame) { ... }
```

> 2. This method tells the delegate that one or more ARAnchors have been added to the session:

```
func session(ARSession, didAdd: [ARAnchor]) { ... }
```

> 3. This method tells the delegate that the ARSession has adjusted the properties of one or more ARAnchors:

```
func session(ARSession, didUpdate: [ARAnchor]) { ... }
```

> 4. This method tells the delegate that one or more ARAnchors have been removed from the ARSession:

```
func session(ARSession, didRemove: [ARAnchor]) { ... }
```

If similar methods (even not all of them) exist in ARCore, please show me how they look like using Kotlin code.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through an ARCore documentation I discovered at least two similar methods:

> **First**: This method is used for receiving a new camera frame, updating the location of the device, updating the location of tracking anchors, updating detected planes, etc.

```
ArStatus ArSession_update(ArSession *session, ArFrame *out_frame)
```

> **Second**: This method defines a tracked location in the physical world:

```
ArStatus ArSession_acquireNewAnchor(ArSession *session, const ArPose *pose, ArAnchor **out_anchor)
```